# Calling function in inside another function

Tags: python

I am create this function

```
def volumn(value_side):

    def side(value_side):
        side = value_side+2
        return (side)

    value_area = side(value_side)

    def area(value_area):
        area = value_area*4
        return(area)

    final_result = area(value_area)
    return(final_result)
```

My question is How If I just want to call `side` function

I have try with this code `volumn(3).side(3)` but still error `int' object has no attribute 'side'`

Comment: `side` and `area` are local variables, not attributes of the return value. You cannot access them outside the function.

Comment: I think they are local functions and not variables. But you're right in that they cannot be accessed from outside the function.

Answer (score 2):

You can return the inner functions `side` and `area` to access them outside

```
def volumn():

    def side(value_side):
        side = value_side+2
        return side

    def area(value_area):
        area = value_area*4
        return(area)

    return side, area


side, area = volumn()
side_value = side(3)
print(side_value)
print(area(side_value))
```

Or you can use a class to encapsulate the functions and attributes

```
class Volumn:

    def __init__(self, value_side):
        self.value_side = value_side

    def side(self):
        side = self.value_side+2
        return side

    def area(self):
        area = self.side()*4
        return area

v = Volumn(3)
print(v.side())
print(v.area())
```

The output will be

```
5
20
```

Answer (score 1):

You could define these functions in the outer scope to access them.

```
def side(value_side):
    side = value_side+2
    return (side)


def area(value_area):
    area = value_area*4
    return(area)


def volume(value_side):
    value_area = side(value_side)
    final_result = area(value_area)
    return final_result
```